# Acceleration of series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

everyone!
I am currently struggling with following problem:
compute the series
$$
\sum\limits_{m=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{m}\sin(m\alpha)(\cos(m\beta_1) - \cos(m\beta_2))
$$
and
$$
\sum\limits_{m=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{m}\sin(m\alpha)(\cos(m\beta_1) - \cos(m\beta_2))\exp(-m^2\gamma)
$$
Where $\alpha \approx 10^{-3}$, $\beta_{1,2} \approx 10^{-3}$ and $\gamma \approx 10^{-6}$,(thus, the parameters are very small). The main problem is in velocity of convergence of these series. Recently I have heard that there is methods of acceleration of convergence of slowly converging series. May be anyone could suggest any such technique? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Computations don't show that... May be because $\gamma$ is tremendously little?..

Comment: Hmm... It is not obviously at all...

Comment: If $\beta_1=\beta_2$ both sums are clearly zero.

Comment: Of course, it is not the case)) They are different.

Comment: Your first sum should be zero regardless so long as the terms $\alpha,\beta_{1,2}$ are greater then or equal to zero and less then $2\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

The first series may be evaluated analytically using

$$f(\gamma)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{m \gamma}}{m} = \begin{cases}\\ \frac{\pi-\gamma}{2} & \gamma \in [0,2\pi)\\ f(\gamma+2 k \pi) & \gamma \in [-2k \pi,-2(k-1) \pi) \end{cases}$$

and

$$\sin{m \alpha} \cos{m \beta} = \frac12 \left [\sin{\left(m\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) }+\sin{\left(m\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \right)}\right ]$$

Note that the sum is not zero because $f(\gamma)$ is a sawtooth rather than a line.

Comment: $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(m\alpha)cos(m\beta)}{m}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{4}$$ for all alpha/beta on $[0,2\pi)$ then, so his first sum should be zero?

Comment: @Ethan: Not necessarily, because the sum is not necessarily a line, but a sawtooth.  Remember that this is a Fourier series.  Nevertheless, given the OP's small values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the sum is likely 0.

Comment: His terms are on $[0,2\pi)$ though

Comment: That's what I meant above.  The sum is zero because they are on the same branch of the sawtooth.